# Start gnome-shell from another session/terminal/user

Tags: gnome

sometimes my gnome shell gets a weird bug. What I need to do then is to click e.g <kbd>Ctrl + Alt + F3</kbd> When I am there i can login and then

```
killall gnome-shell
```

Then I go back to the first <kbd>Ctrl + Alt + F1</kbd> (what do you call them tty1, tty2, tty3 ... )

back there I can sometimes open a terminal and enter:

```
gnome-shell
```

but sometimes it doesn't work, like now, because the browser window has the focus and no other windows has, and I can't start gnome-shell from the browser, so that's why I am asking the question now :) .

The thing that I have tried is to export the display when I am in the tty2 or tty3, not the one with graphics in

```
export DISPLAY=:0.0
gnome-shell
```

but I guess that the :0.0 display isn't the main display?, anyway I can at least start the gnome-shell but it results in an error. It is not the can't find an X display error, but another one that has something to do with the top-bar and the extensions.

Does anyone know how to start the gnome-shell from another "tty" thing?

Comment: ``kill -3 $(pidof gnome-shell)'' to restart gnome

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please try

```
$ DISPLAY=:0 gnome-shell
```

Also you should take a look at your **~/.xsession-errors**, finding out as to why gnome-shell crashed. Maybe you can even do a [backtrace](https://live.gnome.org/GnomeShell/Debugging) and report a bug.

Comment: I get "Window manager error: Unable to open X display :0"

Answer (score 3):

When gnome-shell starts behaving oddly you can also do the following.

1. Switch to another console <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>
2. login using the same account that's running the desktop
3. Run the command `pkill -HUP gnome-shell`

Once the above kill has taken effect, `gnome-shell` will automatically restart itself.

Comment: livesaver, worked when accepted answer does nothing. (note that you may lose your GUI session)

Answer (score 0):

What are you doing it is not possible anymore in wayland sessions, because with Shell having taken the role of the X server, killing it would kill the entire interface. On the bright side shell now is capable or restarting itself when there's a crash or an hang of some sort.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1139191)

Comment: You're right, I didn't check the question correctly, I came here from a search query on how to run shell from tty and after having read just the title and other answers I replied with the answer to what I thought was the question: "how can I run gnome-shell from a tty"?

Answer (score 0):

This happens to me overnight all the time.

What I did this morning was use the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> to open a shell then after doing `pkill gnome` at one point, finally tried `startx` which brought back my desktop.

I have a triple monitor setup and sometimes it's a bit quirky, mainly one monitor doesn't even come on when I reboot until I pull the cable and plug it back in.